# Recursion functions

Tags: scheme, racket

i did the function search that takes a los, a number, and returns the numth symbol of the list. simple

```
(define (search los num)
  (cond
    [(empty? los) empty]
    [(zero? num) (first los)]
    [else (lookup (rest los) (- num 1))]))

(check-expect (lookup (list 'a 'b 'c 'd) 0) 'a)
```

but i am having trouble figuring out how to design a function that takes a los (list of symbols) , a symbol (s) , and a number (numth) , and returns los with numth symbol replaced with s.

like something like this-

```
(change (list 'a 'b 'c 'd) 'hello 2) ;==> (list 'a 'b 'hello 'd)
(change (list 'a 'b 'c 'd) 'hi 0) ;==> (list 'hi 'b 'c 'd)
```

Comment: did you intend to name your function `lookup` and not `search`, perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
(define (change los s num)
  (cond ((null? los) '())
        ((< num 0) los)
        ((= num 0) (cons s (cdr los)))
        (else (cons (car los) (change (cdr los) s (- num 1))))))
```

Basically, the idea is to recreate the list recursively, but with a twist (replacing the nth symbol with s).

So, to recursively "recreate" the list, I could:

```
(define (lst los)
  (if (null? los)
    '()
    (cons (car los) (lst (cdr los)))))
```

Our parameters for `change` give us the symbol to replace with, and the position to replace. So we count down, recreating the list until that point. Then, when we have counted down to 0, we can replace the current symbol in the list with the new symbol by just cons'ing it in instead of the current symbol. I added the `< 0` check just because.

Answer (score 2):

First, think about how to copy a list. This won't involve the `num` parameter.

Then, use the same `num`-decrementing approach you have in `search` to replace (instead of copy) the list element if `num` is 0.